# Windows port forwading

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, port

I got the following setup on an Windows Server 2012 R2:

I have 2 NICs: Nic1 has an public ipv4 address (lets call this 5.5.5.5). Nic2 has an private IP address (192.168.2.10).

So now I want to configure the following:

If someone connect over RDP to the public IP using an non-standard port like 3390, it should be forwarded to the internal IP 192.168.2.10 to port 3389.

In additionally I only want RDP to listen to the internal IP 192.168.2.10.

How is this possible?

Comment: What will it change from having RDP listening on public IP:3390 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use netsh.
In your case the command should look like:

*netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=5.5.5.5 listenport=3390 connectaddress=192.168.2.10 connectport=3389*

This should do the trick.

Comment: so, do i have to open port 3390 in the windows firewall?

Comment: Yes you have otherwise no packet will ever reach the socket.

Comment: so, i opened tcp port 3390 and added the netsh command via administrator-powershell, but now i i want to connect via ip 5.5.5.5 port 3390, the rdp-connection cannot be made.. any clues?

Comment: Can you try using telnet from an external machine to port 3390. If the connection does not timeout it verifies that the FW is correctly configured and the forwarding is working. Can you also check netstat to verify you are listening in 3389 and 3390?

Comment: telnet gives me an timeout on port 3390 and netstat is not listening to 3390..

what i opened in the win-firewall was: port 3390/TCP

Comment: Can you try creating the rule locally and perform the same test from the local machine?
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=3391 connectaddress=192.168.2.10 connectport=3389

Comment: hmm.. no change..

port 3390 is opened in firewall for all ips and all programs.
telnet localhost 3390 failed, 3389 succed

even if i turn of windows firewall nothing changes. any other possible ideas?

Comment: I just realized its not supposed to work with localhost.
Can you test again with the following setup:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=192.168.2.10 listenport=3390 connectaddress=192.168.2.10 connectport=3389

After please check the netstat for port 192.168.2.10:3390. I have tested in Windows 7 and this should work.

Comment: Did the last test work. That would be important to determine to understand the problem.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late answer, i was busy the last days.

yes your last comment worked as expected! thanks a lot! :)